# Trying to load an sqlite table as an ArrayList<String[]> in android

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I'm trying to load an sqlite table as an arraylist so that i can use the data in it. I'm not too sure about the sqlite queries but i already have a class built to manipulate the strings as is, which is what i'm more comfortable with. I can load an individual row but i'm not sure how to get the whole table as an arraylist.

I have the following method in my main method

```
public void ShowCNData()
{
    TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);         
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();       
    mDbHelper.open();

            String allData = mDbHelper.getCYData().get(1)[1];

    thing.setText(allData);

    mDbHelper.close();
}
```

and the following method in my dbAdapter/Helper class

```
 public ArrayList<String[]> getCYData() 
 { 
     ArrayList<String[]> CYData = new ArrayList<String[]>();
     try 
     { 
         String sql ="SELECT * FROM cnYears "; 
         Cursor mCur = null;
         do
         {
             mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
             CYData.add(new String[] {mCur.getString(0),mCur.getString(1),mCur.getString(2),mCur.getString(3),mCur.getString(4)});
         }
         while (mCur.moveToNext());

         return CYData; 
     } 
     catch (SQLException mSQLException)  
     { 
         Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString()); 
         throw mSQLException; 
     } 
 }
```

How do i load the data into my ArrayList?

Comment: currently you are getting only the 1st  row is it?

Comment: Yes. Actually, it is just crashing my app and saying Null Pointer Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Without actual log information, I'd guess your NullPointerException occurs when you get an empty cursor. Try it this way:

```
//initialize arraylist, execute query etc.

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String[] entry = new String[dataSize];

        //pull your data here
        data[0] = cursor.getInt(0);
        data[1] = cursor.getString(1);
        //...

        list.add(entry);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// return arraylist
```